# Sending mail to multiple addresses does not work

Tags: email, bash

I'm trying to setup a post-commit hook on SVN to send mail to a bunch of users using bash scripts. I have successfully setup the hook and it works when only one email address is specified. But when more email addresses are added no mail arrives. The bash scripts are as follows:

post-commit:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
SENDTO="address1@domain.com, address2@domain.com"

# Send it to these people, calling the script we created above
/home/www/svn/bin/svn_email_commit.sh "$REPOS" "$REV" "$SENDTO"
```

svn_email_commit.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
REPOS=$1
REV=$2
SENDTO=$3
SENDFROM=svn@audioaffair.co.uk

LIMITDIFF=200

# Do various other stuff and dump mail body to a temp file $TMPFILE...

# Send email
/bin/cat $TMPFILE | /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$SENDTO"
```

The problem is that /bin/cat $TMPFILE | /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$SENDTO"
does not work if there are multiple $SENDTO addresses. It works when there is only one address.

I'm on CentOS 5.7

Comment: First add an echo for the SENDTO in your second script and add a -v to your mail command to see what is actually happening. I just tested this out by exporting two email addresses to a variable and it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: adding -v to mail gives no additional information

Comment: Thats weird..What about the echo in the second script? It will tell you whether your script reads the input properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the space after the comma:

```
SENDTO="address1@domain.com,address2@domain.com"
```

If that doesn't work try just using sendmail.  Something like this:

```
TMPFILE="/var/tmp/email_test"
EMAIL_SUB = "Subject: Your subject";
EMAIL_TO = "To: address1@domain.com, address2@domain.com";
EMAIL_BCC = "Bcc: address3@domain.com";
echo "$EMAIL_TO" >> ${TMPFILE}
echo "$EMAIL_SUB" >> ${TMPFILE}
echo "$EMAIL_BCC" >> ${TMPFILE}
/usr/lib/sendmail -t < ${TMPFILE}
```

Comment: getting rid of the comma has no effect.

Comment: I solved this using sendmail as ACase suggested, though ACase your script appears to be perl and not bash.
Also got help from http://www.ping.co.il/node/2/

Comment: Oops, cut and paste error.  Cleaned it up.  If your problem is solved you should mark it as answered.